# Use onclick function after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, dom

So I have built one page that all the data gets pulled into. Works great in IE9+ and chrome but need it to work in IE8 and anything that is pulled in through ajax wont work. Code would be something like this.

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/myfile.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: ({'data' : data,}),
    success: function(data){
    $("section").append(data);
    }
});
```

JS

```
function myfunction(data){
//do something
}
```

HTML

```
< button onclick='myfunction(data)' > click here < /button>
```

Note: I know $(something).on(stuff,stuff) will work but that would involve rebuilding all my functions. so trying to avoid that if I can.

Comment: You won't be "rebuilding all my functions" you'll be replacing all your functions with 1 function.

Answer (score 1):

It is because jQuery /JavaScript is unaware of the items that are loaded in myfile.php. The easiest solution is to use `on()` to delegate the events there, so those events will bubble up the DOM tree.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

For instance -

```
$(document).on('click', 'element', function() {
```

Now, when element is clicked the click event bubbles up to document where it will be acted on. The element that the event bubbles up to must exist at the time your jQuery code originally runs so jQuery is 'aware' of the element and can intercept bubbled events to that element. That makes document a fairly safe bet, but you can narrow it down if you desire.

If you don't want to go the easier route you can write event delegation in vanilla JavaScript:

```
// get the parent element, add a click listener...
document.getElementById("element").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // example using a list item
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "li") {
        console.log("list item ", e.target.id.replace("post-"), " was clicked!");
    }
});
```